# Getting a loadNamespace error when triggering an R script from python

Tags: python, r

I'm trying to trigger an R script from a python script. The R script has to run in Microsoft R Server, so instead of trying to run the R code directly, through one of the libraries like rpy2 I'm going the route of executing it with Subprocess.

When I run it, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'jsonlite'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
Approvals list:
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'jsonlite'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Here's the function I'm using in the python script:

```
def runScript():
    rlocation = "/Program Files/Microsoft/ML Server/R_SERVER/bin/x64/Rscript.exe test.r"
    subprocess.run(rlocation)
```

Because the error seems to indicate it's missing a dependency package, I made a simple Hello World package to ensure it wasn't a problem with the script itself needing something installed. R script code is here:

```
print("Hello World")
```

The python script seems to be executing the Rscript.exe, but the program is having issues with the file. But the file itself is so simple it shouldn't be throwing errors. At this point I'm not sure where to troubleshoot next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being to just install the package 'jsonlite'. Despite my script working from the GUI with no issues and not using any packages or dependencies that should be using JSON. For whatever reason, it was required for my script to run directly. That makes no sense to me, but it's working now so... ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Maybe this will help someone else who runs into the same issue.